# Ubuntu 20.04 installer not working

Tags: snap, curtin

Installer looping on error

[image: img_Installer_error]

I am using Cubic to build an Ubuntu appliance ISO. My procedure building the ISO was working up to 16th December but is not working now. The install goes into a cycle every few seconds as per the screen shot. Any ideas on what might have changed and how can I fix it?

The files being added or modified are:

**1. /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/90_autoinstall.cfg**
Create file with the below configuration:

> ```
> #cloud-config
> autoinstall:
>   apt:
>     geoip: true
>     preserve_sources_list: false
>     primary:
>     - arches: [amd64, i386]
>       uri: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>     - arches: [default]
>       uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
>   identity: {hostname: pod-installer, password: password_hash, realname: admin, username: administrator}
>   keyboard: {layout: us, toggle: null, variant: ''}
>   locale: en_US
>   network:
>     ethernets:
>       eth0: {dhcp4: true}
>     version: 2
>   ssh:
>     allow-pw: true
>     authorized-keys: []
>     install-server: true
>   storage:
>     layout:
>       name: lvm
>   version: 1
> ```

**2. /etc/skel/.profile**
The following lines are added to the end to execute a python script at launch:

> ```
> string=administrator check=`whoami`
>
> if [ $string == $check ]; then  
>       sudo sh /etc/path/project/starter.sh fi
> ```

**3. /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service**
The ExecStart line is changed to:

> `ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear --autologin administrator %I $TERM`

**4. /etc/sudoers**
The following line is added to the end of file:

> `administrator ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

**5.  /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head**
Two nameservers are added to the file.

**6. /etc/default/grub**
The line for GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX is changed to:

> `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0"`

**7.  /etc/shadow**
Add root hash by updating root key in the following pattern:

> `root:<root hash>:18521:0:99999:7:::`

**8. ISO Boot  /isolinux/txt.cfg**
`autoinstall` is appended to the labels `live` and `live-nomodeset` only.

Comment: Could this be related to this bug?.. https://bugs.launchpad.net/cubic/+bug/1910408

Comment: Thanks! "customized by Cubic on ...." was appended to the PRETTY_NAME in the /etc/os-release file and to the DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION in the /etc/lsb-release file. Once this was removed, the customized ISO completed the installation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a consequence of Bug [1910408](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cubic/+bug/1910408) in Cubic.

To work around this,..

1. Edit `PRETTY_NAME` in the `/etc/os-release` file.

   ```
   nano /etc/os-release
   ```

   You can add double quotes (`"`) around the value for `PRETTY_NAME`, or you can edit/trim the value to remove spaces.
2. Edit `DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION` in the `/etc/lsb-release` file.

   ```
   nano /etc/lsb-release
   ```

   You can add double quotes (`"`) around the value for `DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION`, or you can edit/trim the value to remove spaces.